# say whether $f(x) = \lfloor (x+1)/2 \rfloor$ is onto

Tags: functions

Consider the floor function $f: R \longrightarrow Z$ given by the rule $f(x) = \lfloor (x+1)/2 \rfloor$

Justify your answer, say whether f is onto.

My prove:

$f(x) = y$

$ \lfloor (x+1)/2 \rfloor = y$

$ x = \lfloor2y - 1\rfloor$ belongs to Z

Thus, $f(x)$ is onto.

Comment: I don't understand: do you need to prove the given function is *surjective* ?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes.

Comment: Then you have rather mixed up the direction. You have to rather that for every $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, that there is $x$ you can plug into your function so that $f(x) =  $y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you meant to ask is a proof for surjectivity of $\;f\;$ , then it's simple: for $\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ , take

$$x:=2m-1\implies f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{2m-1+1}{2}\right\rfloor=m$$

Comment: Thanks. So I should extended my proof, right?

Comment: @Smit  I don't think so. My proof in fact shows the function can even be defined on $\;\Bbb Z\;$ and *still* be surjective. Where do you want to extend your proof to?